# Rasterizing point data

Tags: rasterization, visualisation

I downloaded point-source data of the bumblebee distribution in Europe (Suppl. material 5 from https://doi.org/10.3897/oneeco.3.e28143).

I'm only looking at the composite probability and want to rasterize the data. However, I keep getting errors and cannot seem to make a .tif file out of this.

I want to get the data to look like the map in the article, picture 1 is the point source data, picture 2 is the article. How can I get there?

I have tried "rasterize (vector to raster)" and have also tried converting to geopackage and then rasterizing. Both still give me error 4 and 1 even though data is located in the right place.

[image: point-source data]
[image: map from the article]

Comment: How did you try to rasterize? What settings? What went wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the description of Suppl. material 5: you'll see

- Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area is the projection of the coordinates
- The spatial resolution is 10 km

I don't know much about European projections so assumed "Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area" means [EPSG:3035](https://epsg.io/3035) (ETRS89-extended / Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area Europe).

First add your CSV to  QGIS as a Delimited Text layer and set the CRS to EPSG:3035

[image]

Then export the CSV to a point dataset as the Rasterize (Vector to Raster) tool fails on the CSV. I used a geopackage.

[image]

[image]

Then run the Rasterize (Vector to Raster) tool on the new point dataset. Set the following parameters:

- Field to use for a burn-in value (pick the field that equates to "Bumblebee" or whichever you are interested in)
- Both Width/Horizontal resolution and Height/Vertical resolution to 10000.0 (10,000 metres = 10km = spatial resolution from description)
- Extent to 2640000.0000,6525000.0000,1435000.0000,5300000.0000 (this is the extent of the point layer, shifted 5,000m W and N so each point becomes the centre of the output pixel).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Babel said, your question is a bit vague. But you could use the [Rasterize (vector to raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) tool in QGIS. Or if you are more a command line person, the [rasterize utility](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html) from GDAL, which is behind the QGIS tool.